# Can a new thread block be scheduled only after all warps in previous thread block finish?

Tags: cuda

I wonder if it is possible for an SM to schedule a new thread block even though it is scheduling warps from a previous thread block.

For example, there exists two thread blocks (TB0, TB1).

If TB0 only has 1 warp to finish and it has more jobs, then can warps of TB1 be scheduled on that SM by interleaving warps from TB0 and TB1?

Also, is there any official documentation for this?

Answer (score 2):

No, more than one thread block can be scheduled on one multiprocessor if there are sufficient resources.

Yes, TB0 and TB1 can be scheduled on the same SM, resources permitting - although I would not call that "by interleaving warps".

Yes, this is [documented](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#multiprocessor-level).

Comment: Does it mean that inter-warp load balance within a thread block is minor issue?

Comment: @sungjuncho : It is a minor issue, but not because of what this answer says.